# Query execution time issue

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have some trouble with the execution time of a script. The query takes a lot of time. This is the query:

```
select avg(price) from voiture where duration<30 AND make="Audi" AND model="A4"

+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | SIMPLE | voiture | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 1376949 | Using where |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

select price from voiture where duration<30 AND make="Audi" AND model="A4"
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | SIMPLE | voiture | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 1376949 | Using where |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

This query take around 2 seconds to be executed on the phpMyAdmin interface. I tried to see what the issue was and removing the avg function makes the query lasts around 0.0080 seconds.
I asked myself how long it would take to make the calculate the avg in the php script, but the query with or withouth avg takes around 2 seconds both.
So I decided to take all the values of my table and make the process in the script, so I use this query:

```
select * from voiture where duration<30 AND make="Audi" AND model="A4"

+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | SIMPLE | voiture | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 1376949 | Using where |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

On the phpMyAdmin interface, it takes 0.0112 seconds. But in my php script, it takes 25 seconds !

```
$timestart2=microtime(true);
$querysec='select * from voiture where duration<30 AND make="Audi" AND model="A4"';
$requestsec=mysql_query($querysec) or die(mysql_error());
$timeend2=microtime(true);
$time2=$timeend2-$timestart2;
$page_load_time2 = number_format($time2, 9);
```

Here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `voiture` (
  `carid` bigint(9) NOT NULL,
  `serviceid` bigint(9) NOT NULL,
  `service` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gearingType` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `displacement` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cylinders` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fuel` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mileage` int(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `existFlag` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastUpdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `version` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bodyType` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstRegistration` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `powerHp` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `powerKw` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vat` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pageUrl` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `carImg` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `color` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `doors` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `seats` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prevOwner` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `co2` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `consumption` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gears` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `equipment` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `make` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(3) NOT NULL
)
```

There's an index on carid and serviceid
Why does my query takes so long to be executed ? Is there a way it can be improved ?
Why is the execution time different from phpMyAdmin and my php script ?

Comment: You should provide us more information. What is your table structure, what are you indexing? You could try running an `EXPLAIN` on the query, that should clear up some things. If you don't understand it's output, add it to your question, it would also help us diagnoze the problem.

Comment: How many rows are returned in total with: `select * from voiture where duration<30 AND make="Audi" AND model="A4"` ?

Comment: Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7) Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) its really pretty easy

Comment: Did you try `SELECT price from .....` If you only want the avg of price only retrieve `price`

Comment: Have you indexed `make` and `model`

Comment: @AdamBaranyai I edited my question with more informations, thx for your help

Comment: How large is the table? You are not using indexes when searching. Try adding an index on the `make` field dor example, and see if it fastens things up a bit, or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On the phpMyAdmin interface, it takes 0.0112 seconds. But in my php
>   script, it takes 25 seconds!

phpMyAdmin interface adds `LIMIT` to each query. By default it's `LIMIT 30`.

To decrease time of your aggregate query you need to create indexes for each condition you use(or one composite index, may be).

So, try to create indexes for your `model`, `make` and `duration` fields.

---

Also, your table is too denormalized. You can to create pair of table to normalize it for a bit.
Ex: `Vendors(id, name)`, `Models(id, name)` and modify your `voiture` to have `vendor_id`/`model_id` fields instead of text `make`/`model`.

Then your initial query will look like:

```
select avg(t.price) from voiture t
INNER JOIN Models m ON m.id = t.model_id
INNER JOIN Vendors v ON v.id = t.vendor_id
where t.duration<30 AND v.name="Audi" AND m.name="A4"
```

It will scan light lookup tables for text matches and operate with your heavy table with indexed ids.

Comment: good answer, I added the three index in one composite index, the execution time went from 25 seconds to 1.5 seconds ! I already have a "make" and "model" table but the id of a row is the name of the make/model, that's why I use make="Audi".

Comment: also, I normally use much more parameters than juste the make and the model (almost all the table fields in fact), is it a good thing to put all the field in a composite index ?

Comment: it depends. It will too fat index and search inside of it has no profit against raw table full-scan. Textual primary keys(you use `varchar(256)`) is bad idea too.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible solution, first thing you can do [is create index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) at DB level this can also improve your execution time.

second this check server, there may be some processes which would occupying your server resources, and making your server slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it faster using GROUP BY like

```
select AVG(price) from voiture where duration<30 AND make="Audi" AND model="A4" GROUP BY make
```

Also you can add an index for make column

```
ALTER TABLE `voiture` ADD INDEX `make` (`make`)
```

Comment: i thought about it but in my php script, select price and select avg(price) takes the same time

Comment: I have changed the answer. Please check if this works. @Nevi